# how to fix the java code to show the result as name and score

Tags: java, android, methods

I have provided the xml and java code to 4 question. I work in it and every question have 4 radio buttons and in javam if the user choose the right answer it must add score in the end. The result must show the name and score, but I can't seems to continue from there

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFF00"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:hint="@string/name"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="130dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/Question1"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/firstQuestion"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/GQ11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/GQ11" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/GQ12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/GQ12" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/GQ13"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/GQ13" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/GQ14"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/GQ14" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="130dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/Questuin2"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/secondQuestion"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/GQ21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/GQ21" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/GQ22"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/GQ22" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/GQ23"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/GQ23" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/GQ24"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/GQ24" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="130dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/Question3"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/thirdQuestion"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/GQ31"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/GQ31" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/GQ32"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/GQ32" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/GQ33"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/GQ33" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/GQ34"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/GQ34" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="130dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/Question4"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/fourthQuestion"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/GQ41"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/GQ41" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/GQ42"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/GQ42" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/GQ43"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/GQ43" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/GQ44"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:text="@string/GQ44" />
    </RadioGroup>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/end"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:onClick="result"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

**Java Class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int score = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public int answersQ1(View view) {
        RadioButton aq1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GQ11);
        RadioButton aq2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GQ12);
        RadioButton aq3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GQ13);
        RadioButton aq4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GQ14);
        if (aq1.isChecked()) {
            score = score + 1;
        } else if (aq2.isChecked() && (aq3.isChecked() && (aq4.isChecked()))) {
            score = score + 0;
        }
        return score;

    }

    public int answersQ2(View view) {
        RadioButton ab1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GQ21);
        RadioButton ab2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GQ22);
        RadioButton ab3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GQ23);
        RadioButton ab4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GQ24);
        if (ab2.isChecked()) {
            score = score + 1;
        } else if (ab1.isChecked() && (ab3.isChecked() && (ab4.isChecked()))) {
            score = score + 0;
        }
        return score;
    }

    public int answersQ3(View view) {
        RadioButton ac1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GQ31);
        RadioButton ac2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GQ32);
        RadioButton ac3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GQ33);
        RadioButton ac4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GQ34);
        if (ac2.isChecked()) {
            score = score + 1;
        } else if (ac1.isChecked() && (ac3.isChecked() && (ac4.isChecked()))) {
            score = score + 0;
        }
        return score;
    }

    public int answersQ4(View view) {
        RadioButton ad1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GQ41);
        RadioButton ad2 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GQ42);
        RadioButton ad3 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GQ43);
        RadioButton ad4 = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.GQ44);
        if (ad1.isChecked()) {
            score = score + 1;
        } else if (ad2.isChecked() && (ad3.isChecked() && (ad4.isChecked()))) {
            score = score + 0;
        }
        return score;

    }

    public void result (View view){
     // userName
        EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        Editable nameEditable = nameField.getText();
        String name = nameEditable.toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), name , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), score, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


}
```

When I press button **submit** the app crashes.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Your code is too long. Try making a shorter version that works correctly first. Also, if you are saying "the app crashes" - you should also say how it crashes, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: when i press submit button the app crash the result must be like name ...... score ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application crashes because you don't have an onClickListener. You need one to handle the button click. It should look something like this:

```
Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submit);
clickButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO
            }
        });
```

Inside the onClick method you want to perform the checks for the answers and anything you want to happen after the submit button is clicked. Additionally, since you have a long LinearLayout I would suggest you add a ScrollView.

Comment: thanks for your comment i have scrollview at first the problem the score doesn't appear and the name in first

Comment: @kamal You have functions for questions 1 to 4 and for the result but you are never calling those functions to check the answers. In your onClick function you want to call those to check and add the score and then call the result function to make the toast. You should review your functions first, because there is some faulty logic in them. For instance your `else if` clauses are redundant if you aren't adding or subtracting points if the answer is wrong. You should also probably use a variable local to those functions and return that instead of using the `score` variable.